# Migrating from Fossil SCM to GitHub

Tags: git, github, fossil

For a project I have been maintaining the versions in `Fossil SCM`. Now I want to move it to GitHub. So I did the following steps as referenced in the below URLs.

I created a repository on GitHub without readme, license and .gitignore and issued the following commands.

```
git init
git add *
fossil export --git repo.fossil | git fast-import
git remote add origin github_repo_url.git
git remote -v
git push origin mast
```

After this when I view in `GitHub`, I see only one commit, but I have almost 30 commits in `Fossil SCM`. I need to get all the commits. How can I do that?

Reference URLs:
 * [Fossil Export to Git](http://fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/trunk/www/inout.wiki)
 * [GitHub import existing project](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/#platform-linux)

Comment: It looks as if you may be missing a few steps in the export. Make sure that your repo fossil is outside of your new-repo git folder. That is why in the documentation you reference it points one level up to `../repo.fossil`. Check with `git log` inside the new the git working directory that the export included all commits. And only then proceed to push to github.